# Binary avro type mapping to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi, avro

I have the following avro definition for my Nifi flow, where i'm reading a from a BLOB database column. I'm mapping the 'xxPZPVSTREAM' column as a 'bytes' type in my avro definition

```
{
    "namespace":"a.b.c",
    "name":"pc_history",
    "type":"record",
    "fields":   [
        {"name":"COMMITDATETIME","type":["null",{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"}]},
        ....
        {"name":"xxPZPVSTREAM","type":["bytes","null"]},
        {"name":"xxx","type":["string","null"]}
    ]
}
```

When i attempt to write the mapped data to a Postgres database i get this error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can’t infer the SQL type to use for an instance of [Ljava.lang.Byte;. Use setObject() woth an explicit Types values to specify the type to use.
```

Can i add extra meta information to the avro definition to allow the Nifi processor to correctly map this binary column?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which processor you're using, but this should be supported by `PutDatabaseRecord`. That processor is what you'd want to use for this as it should map byte array fields to a blob. If it doesn't, then please join the nifi-dev mailing list and let us know.

Comment: thanks - it was a ExecuteSQLRecord processor where we're trying to read a serialized blob from an oracle DB, the query was fine by the mapping to avro schema failed with the error above.